# 'default_random_engine' is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I have found many questions to this topic but all problems seem to be related to not compiling with C++ 11. My code is

```
#include <random>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    return 0;   
}
```

even though I compile with

```
gcc -std=c++0x testmain.cpp
```

Giving the error that default_random_engine is not a member of std. The program is compiled on a remote machine, which I do not maintain myself but

```
gcc -v
```

yields a version of 4.4.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: GCC version 4.4 is very old, and doesn't support of all the C++11 standard. Notably the random-number functionality is missing.

Comment: Can you install anything on the remote machine? Or does it have `boost` installed?

Comment: Either use Boost or the TR1 random library. For the latter, `#include <tr1/random>`. I don't think it has a `default_random_engine`, so you'll have to use something else, maybe `std::tr1::mt19937`

Comment: @Praetorian Sorry I posted my answer before seeing your comment.

Answer (score 7):

For others:
**Check if you actually include random with `#include <random>`.** I didn't have it and some other header included it previously. Now that header got updated and I got this error and didn't find it for a while because I was checking compiler settings.

Comment: This should be also included in your header file, too.

Answer (score 6):

As DevSolar already stated, your gcc version is too old, to support this C++11 feature.

It was added in **gcc-4.5**:

> Improved experimental support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard,
>   C++0x, including:
>
> Support for `<future>`, `<functional>`, and `<random>`.

*Reference:* https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html

This is also reflected by the libstdc++ API Reference:  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a01118.html

where you can find the following:

```
 typedef minstd_rand0 default_random_engine
```

---

Your code works fine for me in: `gcc-5.1.0`, `gcc-4.9.2` and `clang-3.7.0`,

Also you should use the `command`: **g++** instead of **gcc** so gcc links against proper c++ libraies by default.

Comment: hmmm .. why would somebody downvote my answer? Tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @juanchopanza ok, I see your point. Did a little research and fixed it.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're not compiling with C++11. ;-) (Sorry, could not resist.)

GCC 4.4.7 is dated March 2012. C++11 support was not yet complete in that version.

As of the time of this writing, the current version of GCC is 5.2.0... which is C++**14** compliant. Time to update your compiler. ;-)

Comment: Thing is, I can't as this is a remote machine I don't own.

Comment: @Hagadol: Bugger the owner of the machine to update the system. If the GCC is that old, other components probably are, as well. Outdated system software is not a mere nuisance, it's a **security risk**. (Think about the bugs in SSL that have only recently been fixed, for just one example.) If it's a customer, tell him you cannot guarantee proper behaviour on such an outdated machine. If it's a provider, *demand* up-to-date system software for your money. If you're not in a position to do (or initiate others to do) this, you'll need a different solution for your randomness.

Comment: @Hagadol: All this being said, be aware that it's not that much of a problem to install an up-to-date compiler for your user (instead of updating the system compiler). `./configure --prefix=${HOME}/.local_software && make install` plus `export PATH=${HOME}/.local_software:${PATH}`. Note, however, that any libraries you might generate with that compiler might not be compatible for use with the *system* compiler...

Answer (score 0):

I hate to recommend this but in your case (old untouchable machine) I can offer a suggestion.  The tr1 version of the random library should be available for g++-4.4:

```
#include <tr1/random>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::tr1::default_random_engine generator;
    return 0;   
}
```

There have been improvements in the `std` version relative to `tr1` version but you should be able to use most `<random>` features.

You don't even need C++0x.